# Random alert pops up and stops my code... even though I never called for it? Selenium WebDriver w Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code

```
@Test(enabled=creditCard, priority=8)
public void creditCard() throws InterruptedException{
    Browser.isURLCorrect("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/medellin/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    home.clearCart();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    commonRepeats.goToProduct("chocolates", 5);
    product.comprar();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    checkout.billingInfo(typeOfDocument, docnumber, emailaddress, passwrd);
    checkout.recipient(typeofhouse, sector);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    checkout.submit();
//          
}






public static void isURLCorrect(String URL){
    if (driver==null)
        openBrowser(URL);

    String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    if (currentURL==URL)
        System.out.println("correct URL");
    else
        driver.navigate().to(URL);

}






public static void clearCart(){
    WebElement itemNum = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='badge']"));

    if(!itemNum.getText().contains("0")){
        WebElement carrito = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Mi carrito']"));
        carrito.click();
        cart.emptyCart();
    }




public static void goToProduct(String Category, int nthITEM) throws InterruptedException{
    home.chooseCategory(Category);
    category.chooseItem(nthITEM);
}




public static void comprar(){
    WebElement comprar = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("btn_buy_detail"));
    comprar.click();
}









public static void billingInfo (String typeOfDoc, String document, String emailaddy, String pass) throws InterruptedException{
    WebElement first = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("billing:firstname"));
    WebElement last = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("billing:lastname"));
    WebElement email = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("billing:email"));
    WebElement phone = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("billing:telephone"));
    WebElement male = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("billing:gender1"));
    WebElement female = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("billing:gender2"));
    WebElement distinct = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mw_onstepcheckout_billing_form']/ul/li[10]/div/label"));   
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    if (first.getAttribute("value").equals("")){
        WebElement login = Browser.driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("registrarse"));
        login.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement usern = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("mini-login"));
        WebElement passn = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("mini-password"));
        WebElement goLogin = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Iniciar Sesión']"));
            if(!usern.getAttribute("value").equals(""))
                usern.clear();
        usern.sendKeys(emailaddy);
            if(!passn.getAttribute("value").equals(""))
                passn.clear();
        passn.sendKeys(pass);
        goLogin.click();
            if(Browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/medellin/checkout/cart/")){
                WebElement empty = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Eliminar artículo']"));
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Actions act = new Actions(Browser.driver);
                act.moveToElement(empty);
                empty.click();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                WebElement close = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ajax-messagebox']/div/a"));
                close.click();
                WebElement finalizar = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Finalizar Pedido']"));
                finalizar.click();
            }
    }

    WebElement doctype = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("billing:document-type"));
    WebElement doc = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("billing:document"));

    final String CC = "Cédula Colombiana";
    final String CE = "Cédula Extranjería";
    final String NIT = "NIT";
    final String TI = "Tarjeta de Identidad";
    final String PA = "Pasaporte";
    final String RC = "Registro Civil";
    final String NSS = "Número de Seguridad Social";
    final String LC = "Licencia Conducción";
    final String II = "Identificación Impositiva";

    Select dtype = new Select(doctype);
    switch(typeOfDoc){
        case CC:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(CC);
            break;
        case CE:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(CE);
            break;
        case NIT:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(NIT);
            break;
        case TI:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(TI);
            break;
        case PA:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(PA);
            break;
        case RC:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(RC);
            break;
        case NSS:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(NSS);
            break;
        case LC:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(LC);
            break;
        case II:
            dtype.selectByVisibleText(II);
            break;

    }

    doc.sendKeys(document);



}
public static void recipient(String type, String sector) throws InterruptedException{
    /*WebElement first = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("shipping:firstname"));
    WebElement last = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("shipping:lastname"));
    WebElement phone = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("shipping:telephone"));
    WebElement street = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("shipping:street1"));
    */




    WebElement street2 = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("shipping:street2"));
    street2.sendKeys(type);

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement dropdown = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sector']/div/div"));
    dropdown.click();
    WebElement textbox = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='shipping_address_form']/li[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input"));
    textbox.sendKeys(sector, Keys.ENTER);
    WebElement textbox2 = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='shipping_address_form']/li[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input"));
    textbox2.click();
    WebElement textbox3 = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='shipping_address_form']/li[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/input"));
    textbox3.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    //WebElement paymentmethod = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("p_method_placetopay_standard"));
    //paymentmethod.click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement calbutton = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='delivery_dates']/div[1]/div/span"));
    calbutton.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement date = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]"));
    date.click();

}

public static void submit(){
    WebElement accept = Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("id_accept_terms"));
    WebElement next = Browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Hacer un pedido']"));

    accept.click();
    next.click();
}
```

The issue is whenever I click the final button on the last checkout page, I receive an alert sometimes. The alert looks like this. [alert I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eHsz.png)

I am not really sure what else to add as details, but stack is requiring me to add more so I will try to describe more about my problem.

I am working on this e-commerce site and I have three tests running on that final checkout page that all do the same thing.. fill out the info and try to checkout! The difference between the three is each one chooses a different payment method.

Comment: Seems it is an environment coding issue. Try to reproduce if possible and talk with a dev.

Comment: Reproducing is no issue, occurs regularly when I try to run all the tests in succession, I get no alert if I run only one of the test. I asked someone over at the website's office and he's going to message the dev.

Comment: What error occurred when this alert popup??..and random means popup anywhere on the code or only some specific action?? and what do you want with this popup?? Do you want disable it, it should never occur when you run your test or something else??

Comment: I attached the image to a link in my description, that's what the alert looks like!

Answer (score 0):

As this test has dependencies can you try and run the whole sequence of tests manually (this is the 8th test). Check if the javascript error pops up then.
Have you tried running the tests on some other browser?

Comment: I'm gonna try to run it on a different browser right now.. should've tried that before! What do you mean by run the whole sequence manually? like run each one after the other ends? It works fine if i do that